Where is finiteness of $G$ used in proof? Statement: $N\unlhd G$, $G$ finite, and $|N|,[G:N]$ coprime. Then $\{a\in G\mid a^{|N|}=e\}\subseteq N$.
The following is Problem 9.33 and its given solution from Davvaz's,
"A First Course in Group Theory."
The Proof in Question:

Problem 9.33: Let $N$ be a normal subgroup of a finite group $G$. If $|N|$ and $[G:N]$ are relatively prime, prove that any element $a\in G$ satisfying $a^{|N|}=e$ must belong to $N$.
Solution: Suppose that $a\in G$ such that $a^{|N|}=e$. Since $([G:N], |N|)=1$, it follows that there exist integers $m$ and $n$ such that $m[G:N]+n|N|=1$. Then, we deduce that
$$\begin{align}
a&=a^{m[G:N]+n|N|}\\
&=a^{m[G:N]}a^{n|N|}\\
&=a^{m[G:N]}\left(a^{|N|}\right)^n\\
&=a^{m[G:N]}.
\end{align}$$
Now, we consider $aN$ as an element of $G/N$. Then, we have $(aN)^{|G/N|}=a^{|G/N|}N=N$, the identity element of $G/N$. This yields $a^{|G/N|}\in N$, and consequently, $a=\left(a^{[G:N]}\right)^m\in N$.

The Question:

Where is the finiteness of $G$ used in the proof?

Thoughts:
Hmmm . . . I hoped that, in typing it out verbatim, I would see it; I don't.
Coprimality of the order of the normal subgroup with its index seems to me the only hypothesis used, other than, of course, that $a^{|N|}=e$.
Their being coprime implies they're finite.

"If $|N|$ and $[G:N]$ are coprime" implicitly states that both $|N|$ and $[G:N]$ are finite, which is impossible if $G$ is infinite.

So? It should be a corollary, not a hypothesis, then, @Asigan.

My view on how statements should be worded is that, when reading, each symbol should be clearly defined before it is introduced. By stating that $G$ is finite the statement author "allows" themselves to write about the coprime-ness of the cardinality of two sets (as they are finite, so integers). If he ommited this, the statement "If $|N|$ and $[G:N]$ are relatively prime" makes no sense, as being coprime is only (commonly) defined for integers.

If you want to let $G$ be infinite, you run into the fact that one of the quantities $|N|$ and $|G/N|$ is infinite. The definition of "relatively prime" ordinarily requires that one be given two integers. If you with to use an extended definition of relatively prime to allow one to be given two objects that need not  be integers, then it is incumbent on you to explain how the definition is to be extended to cover that case. Perhaps your intention is that two things that are not integers are not relatively prime, but this kind of "definition by exclusion" is not standard in mathematics.

Two points:

If you assume that $|N|$ and $[G:N]$ are finite, then $G$ is finite. So in principle, you could write


Suppose that $N$ is a normal subgroup of a group $G$. If $|N|$ and $[G:N]$ are finite and relatively prime, prove that ...

But this trivial reformulation is a bit bizarre, and will confuse the reader. Why aren't you just saying that $G$ is finite?
As others have pointed out, it is better to start out by saying that $G$ is finite. Then the statement that $|N|$ and $[G:N]$ are relatively prime makes sense, and we do not need to mention their finiteness.

The argument in the proof works more generally. For example, with the same proof you get the following:


Suppose that $N$ is a normal subgroup of $G$ such that $G/N$ is finite. Let $x \in G$ be such that $x^k = 1$ for some integer $k$ with $\gcd(k,|G/N|)= 1$. Then $x \in N$.


We need $N$ and $G/N$ to be finite for the statement to make sense. But these two are both finite if and only if $G$ is finite.

But their finiteness follows from their coprimality!

In that case the assumption that $G$ is finite is not used. Including it in the statement is redundant.

I thought so! I'd like someone to articulate why just to be sure. If you [edit] your answer to include these details, I will be likely to accept it.

I guess I understand pedagogically why they'd include it. That doesn't mean I like it.

It is very common in mathematics that superfluous assumptions or definitions arise, see for example here: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/54933/superfluous-definitions

There is nothing ‘superfluous’. It is just plain bizarre to mention that N and G/N have relatively prime orders without mentioning that G is finite. The phrasing of the question is completely fine whereas the OPs question serves no purpose at all.
